# How to type a recursive intersection, with refactor in mind?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am trying to refactor the following piece of code so I can reuse the same middleware logic on multiples pages in a typesafe manner. However, I am having some hard time in writing a typesafe recursive type that works for the following use case.

Working original code:

```
import { NextPage, GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next';

// new InferGetServerSidePropsType fix, waiting for merge to stable
type InferGetServerSidePropsType<T extends (args: any) => any> = Awaited<
  Extract<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>, { props: any }>['props']
>;

const getServerSideProps = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) =>
  (async (context, props) => {
    const token = 'token';
    if (Math.random() > 0.5)
      return {
        notFound: true,
      };
    return (async (context, props) => {
      if (context.locale === 'en')
        return {
          redirect: {
            destination: '/en',
            permanent: true,
          },
        };
      const permissions = [1, 2, 3];
      return (async (context, props) => {
        const data = 'data';
        return { props: { ...props, data } };
      })(context, { ...props, permissions });
    })(context, { ...props, token });
  })(context, {});

const MyPage: NextPage<InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>> = (props) => {
  const { token, permissions, data } = props; // types are infered correctly!
  return null;
};
```

[Playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgOQKYA8YAUCGBzVAGjgHFUYBlVKAN2ouABNUsoIwBnAYQgDsYM8AL5wAZmxBwA5L0FSA3AFgAUCoD0auLIDucAJK9R1MpWp0oDZq3YcAKgE8wqMcHTFtOYDGC88Y6HAg1ARwMBBwHDA4AEYANqgqGJCwoY7OBkZQJlS09EwsbJwOTgA8tnCCqLyMHHAAFDhQeBwAXHA4vPYAlHAAvAB87Z2DvXAAgh5eqIwlKnBwAKKYUDgAxjAlE54CMwBK5ACuULzFqGX9-cRIYIWtQ-ZwQv0A2lI3NlIAuir9SqrKqz4kTgBFMuQs%20WsnD67Q49l4q3qgP4gja2TMeSstx4KMwPQGc3qODhCKRfAEmGI704%20MGCEJ82RwLCAGsqjCpKyqgoGXBgKJ6gBZHAwAAWADoVtUICA6j1BgAGcUAVi6vPmUEOx0Q6vmWggMAAYhADtU2jAoAciLqhH89XBNTAjrwiSTEXVkRSYFTbrSdcp7fN%20WTcTBxbEIKscPE%20r1RlJuWqA4GNVqXfTkynU4xgJr1m0M1nA8xIj4RcA%20G0pGpuYRdSmnFAQB0qjBzZbrZms0I6137bbdUz4I2QMAOBwK7xaqNngBGYgAJmIAGZPnbA47na74e7PYIfTY-YWs0O4IwRTgOeeojy%203rN9rrrcC3BxW-qRxiNfLyIB3ehF0HrkvuiCvu%20txUtQo7jpOtQAeu8wAUBoZXGB4ofsQXIuvBhJIXulKIDh-xJNA8CnoK9i4AQbRoJgVFnBkxjkDk5iWAUNinCUMBpBAAqgixmLsZwFwwnUH5HoSp5IFhkFNmOE5Al%20F6PDCH7yHAGipE4tSNM4PiZNMcCAlAeYwLE9gAISEg%20Lq8AcsSxH8tpAA)

In my first attempt to type a recursive intersection between middlewares I came with this broken code:

```
const withToken: GSSPMiddleware<{ token: string }> = (next) => async (context, props) => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5)
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  const token = 'token';
  return next(context, { ...props, token });
};

const withPermissions: GSSPMiddleware<{ permissions: number[]}> = (next) => async (context, props) => {
  if (context.locale === 'en')
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/en',
        permanent: true,
      },
    };
  const permissions = [1, 2, 3];
  return next(context, { ...props, permissions });
};

const getServerSideProps = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) =>
  withToken(
    withPermissions(async (context, props) => { // props: {token: string} & {permissions: number[]}
      const data = "data";
      return { props: { ...props, data } };
    })
  )(context, {});

const MyPage: NextPage<InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>> = (props) => {
  const { token, permissions, data } = props; // types should infer correctly!
  return null;
};

// My attempt, completely wrong
type GSSPMiddleware<Params extends { [key: string]: any } | undefined = undefined> = <
  P extends { [key: string]: any } = { [key: string]: any },
>(
  next: (
    context: GetServerSidePropsContext,
    props: Params extends undefined ? P : P & Params
  ) => Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<Params extends undefined ? P : P & Params>>
) => (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext,
  props: P
) => Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<Params extends undefined ? P : P & Params>>;
```

How should I refactor this code and write this type?

Comment: Missing definitions for `ParseUrlQuery`.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvGQQw) what your problem is? It's hard to tell what is happening because of all the extra Next.js-specific BS. It would **greatly** help if you could simplify your problem into an example that does not require Next.js-specific things. Like in my example, I've tried to replicate your problem without needing Next.js. Does it do it justice or am I missing something?

Comment: I have a type-safe multi-middleware solution here https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-eqqhbs?file=pages%2Fapi%2Fhello.ts . Not sure you can use 1:1 but it is a good start

Answer (score 0):

i have made a type impl that currently ignores the implementation of the actual method and only adds up the properties that are passed by the typing

the props param is currently typed to an empty object which would be very hard to type correctly as the "main" object comes from the last call

```
type GSSPMiddleware<AddingParams extends { [key: string]: any } = {}> = <
  NextFnc extends <T>(context:GetServerSidePropsContext,props:{})=>any,
  CustomProps extends {} = {}
>(
  next: NextFnc
)  => <ParentProps>(context:GetServerSidePropsContext,props:ParentProps & CustomProps)=>Promise<{
  props:AddingParams 
  } & (Awaited<ReturnType<NextFnc>> extends {props:infer Pr}?{props:Pr}:{}) & ParentProps >;
```

on second thought typing the props doesnt really make sense, cause inside the props implementation you cannot know the order in which they are nested inside each other

[link to playground with complete solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgOQKYA8YAUCGBzVAGjgHFUYBlVKAN2ouABNUsoIwBnAYQgDsYM8AL5wAZmxBwA5L0FSA3AFgAUCoDGfDvADuwGAAsAKhADWqXgC5SFClgCyTRgBtU2nFFQAeJDFPmrWlDAvHhwQgB8cAC8cAAUspgAlNGROBwAnrxqcRr8gsRgbJwWCB4aUAD8FoHBeELJUZEIKnBwwKJxdjgGAHRQOLyMECCxyZEADD0ArIktrXAeMACuULyIc-NwvBAwAGIQS4NWMFBLRBthSsqtuVpwvmZrMVIP5gpziytrCTCxuQKYYhIHogwrsDjEV5repXIRXdSaHR6fRYaggYAcDjATRWEg2eyOFxuDzeOBgNEYrE4rZLEAAI2oAG0ALoRaJxH4NVIZLI5PgAmAFIocLnra5wObtPl5TA9JwQNQ4FzRKLPN6zcWtT6rMWbLWoRjAMowKzNTV65haYLdbGWaQAejehAum3JUBAA3MJvup3O5taQmd5rhc1u8Dd6Mxto47MZAEZiAAmYgAZmZV31yx1Pz%20-PyiDgIJ6YM4BQpUc0YUSsPhqmU9vtW1ccAAkrxRNQyJRqHQoAxmKxwYZ0uSxMB0MQ3HpamJoHAQNQCPcIHAtDg6S4VBhILB7iPUK3253yFRaPQmCxhcPyZ5DHBBOZGDHYu48BwrAN0qLP5EYgBBKcBEYTw5gAUUwfo1BgTwAJwPQDU8AAlcgvmvLxDHCcIgTJYUP14dIwnCRkpBLDgpGZFRwnkAA2FQ6OUMM4AIbszz7C9B04dk0kybJcxlb0u1PXt%200vcEeH4rk5l0AxjEeWILmklFyypXgOBfHleP%20fNSNFJAGxw8FTShAITlqEQADJEAjSloysXhaQZKAWSEF04EYxhuhwdkACIPJgHBvIzPVtTWJBSNNQtQWFYg-K8kQQ2DDVWkSPiBSBGF6JUZg1CcdwDxodw3JgdALE-FR7QAKlaBFVPgZihPPAdhS4jTpQFXETx7RrRM4cSBS5M0KvtOYVBccM0Q4KJFNRd0bM0dSeLa7ThV0uB9PCxBjNXUyQgsqzlNsml6SZVlXJCgsNoQAQtAsONExTeKgoDFKoInBB6ky5QxvuKIcEAskJquGBi2FYsDs0FRgdInprpgcqKsh-c4A4jg0NvX84DvB9BhjBBwuCDsoGRoQKiwCxZF7RHRxmkAln8mBbV2LJPCwNCMdve9MEfGNWf3KJefJcJUsECxBK6timrEvNAXCwxEkaT8hvomAkbxWwHEYZxXDymDNdqXB%20hAGNsafAtGTMdITKCEJmTwgiRBid72bmNBMCZ7ITZjdHhcwUXOtYkSUb6-Jwve%20Xwk-INWi4JYtGGFHOYEHHEAdlPKPk8UfisV29iyFRkhSOAWby-gUaFrTfbFgP2OFYOZdwg2vQTyyY7jkAUfDwdIy8M1WnCv89ZCA2cCNiVxT22JYPg4DkKzXg0Zz93MMT7mrNwgnqGRqASbxhvt5Keo4EsxvS%20aqjPu3aB4EYux0lwAhs8Ee%20vDbQmq%20Emuh33TwVfJCAOnquLQOwpl4xFiDpQuvc3KIgLFCMss0KyqRip5MI7JSLyDWo2X%20qAYx5TaEeDwjBoFQGNE4dIABCD4KFsxLCcE4GsQA)

Comment: This example does not allow to reuse logic between pages, which is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: ah yeah my bad those callbacks are standins for the middleware methods , i got too focused on the playground

Comment: anyway the type above works in the playground - tho it is always possible that the middleware methods arent generic enough to correctly pass through the types

Comment: ok i added a new version , ive reduced the typing a bit inside the middleware the input param 'props' is only typed to empty object currently (if u plan to only use destructuring for follow up ojbects that shouldnt be a problem)- if you definitely need to have that one typed as well its gonna get even more complex and i can look at it later

Comment: ok now you can also specify props types inside the middlwares in the format of 

`(context, props:{myprop?:string}) => { ...` // always optional